# Two expanders beside each other wont expand the latter

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, expander

For some reason when I set two expanders beside one another, the first expander seems to be behind the second one and wont expand out the expander set beside it? Is there a way I can fix this in the code below?

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,195,0">
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded" SourceName="expander"> 
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.35" Storyboard.TargetName="listBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>                                
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Expander x:Name="expander" Expanded="expander_Expanded" ExpandDirection="Right" Width="29">
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ListBox.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="1"/>
                </ListBox.LayoutTransform>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,342,0" Width="318">
            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded" SourceName="expander1">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.35" Storyboard.TargetName="listBox1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" Name="expander1" Width="29">
            <ListBox Name="listBox1">
                <ListBox.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="1" />
                </ListBox.LayoutTransform>
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Stop using irrelevant tags please, this is neither *about* XML nor HTML.

Comment: Part of the problem may be the use of two stackpanels- why not just use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Width="29"` in

```
<Expander x:Name="expander"
          Expanded="expander_Expanded"
          ExpandDirection="Right"
          Width="29">
```

and all will be okay.

Comment: is there a way to also increase the size of the expander?

Comment: Why? The Size of Expander depends on content. There are different values for collapsed and expanded state as you can see in `Expander.ActualWidth` property.

Comment: No sorry I ment the size of the expander in the closed state.

Comment: I would try `Margin` or `Padding`.